# Checking for argument in custom factor with dplyr::mutate crashes RStudio

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I've got a custom function which I want to use with dplyr mutate. However, the absence of a required argument causes RStudio to crash. I'm not sure whether this is a bug with dplyr or RStudio or desired behaviour.

I'd like to check for a missing argument and stop without crashing RStudion.

The error message I get is

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've been using `missing()` but this also happens with `stopifnot()`.

```
require(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(year = c(201314, 201415), val = c(1,2), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test_fun <- function(x, year_format){
  year_format_list <- c("fyear6", "fyear4", "cyear2")
  if(missing(year_format))
    stop("Year format must be supplied")
  z <- x + 1
  return(z)
}

dat$year2 <- test_fun(dat$year)

dat <- mutate(dat, year3 = test_fun(year))
```

sessionInfo:

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.2       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.3.0 DBI_0.4        tools_3.3.0   
[7] Rcpp_0.12.4
```

RStudio version 0.99.896

Comment: What is the `x` argument for in `function(x, year_format)`?

Comment: Oops, it should have been numeric, but actually it doesn't matter, the crash still occurs. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: My guess is that the behavior has to do with R, not rstudio. You can verify this by running your program in terminal.